# how can i get the number of times a specific word occur in my sql

Tags: mysql

Please how can I get the number of times, a specific word occur in a table?
I have a table called result and a field  called president.

```
Index - president  
1 - James  
2 - John  
3 - John  
4 - John  
5 - James  
6 - John
```

I tried using the following codes to get the number of times John occur in my table.

```
SELECT COUNT(`president`) FROM `result` WHERE `president`="John"
```

But, it's writing syntax error.
N.B: What I just need is the number of times John appeared which I expected to be four(4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this mate:

```
SELECT
    president, COUNT(index) 'occured'
FROM
    result
WHERE
    president = 'John';
```

**E:** This one is specific for 'John' only.

```
SELECT
    president, COUNT(index) 'occured'
FROM
    result
GROUP BY
    president;
```

**E:** To display the count for each result.president in your database. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, it works, I had to change that 'index' to 'index_president', because 'index' is a reserved word.
But another challenge I'm facing now is, how to display the number(i.e number of times 'John' occured) through php .

Comment: <?php

 $sql = 'SELECT \'president\', COUNT( \'index_president\' ) \'occured\''
        . ' FROM score'
        . ' WHERE president = "John"';
   
  
   $comm = mysql_query($sql,);
   
   if($comm){
    echo "John = <br/>";
    echo $comm;
    
   }
   else
    echo "Error has occured";
    
 ?>
 
But unfortunately, this is the output I received;

John =
Resource id #4


Please, help me out.

Comment: try this, mate:

<?php
 $sql = "SELECT president, COUNT(index_president) 'occured' FROM score WHERE president = 'John';";
 $comm = mysql_query($sql);
 if($comm){ echo "John = <br/>"; echo $comm; } else echo "Error has occured";
?>

Comment: The output is: Error has occured. Which mean $comm is not true.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use COUNT on a column. In your case, you want to get
*the number of rows where the president is 'John'*.

Use the following syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `result` WHERE `president` = "John"
```

P.S. Don't call your table `result`. It is kind of incorrect in terms of naming and architecture in general. Call it `PresidentsHistory` or `PresidentsList`.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax `` COUNT(`president`) `` is not correct.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `result` WHERE `president` = "John"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  try the below query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `result` WHERE `president` LIKE "John"
```